# Sell stocks or borrow money from a friend to pay my credit card bill?

Tags: stocks, credit-card

I began working as a full-time Data Analyst 5 months back. I am from India, I make $500 a month and I have $10 in my savings account.

I have about $900 invested in a company which I believe has the potential to return 3 times my investment in a year.

My credit card bill is $760 and the due date is next Monday (4 days away).

I see two possibilities:

1. Borrow $760 from my friend and pay him back in 2 months. I'll be broke for two months and then I'll be fine. But I don't know how I will survive during these two months.
2. Sell my stocks and pay the credit card bill.

However, I don't want to end my investment.  I am unable to make a final decision.  How do I resolve this situation wisely?

Comment: The credit card bill is irrelevant; would you borrow $760 from a friend, invest in the stock market, and then pay your friend back 2 months from now (either by selling stock or other means)? If the answer is no, then don't borrow the money.

Comment: "I have about $900 invested in a company which I believe has the potential to return 3 times my investment in a year." - Can you get this money back? Anyone who promised 3x return in a year is likely scamming you.

Comment: If you believe an investment is particularly likely to triple/quadruple your money in a year (or give you anything more than like a 10% return, or maybe 20% in some rare cases), I'd be willing to put money on either that being a scam or you greatly misjudging how likely success is.

Comment: Sorry to break it to you, but the company will not return 3 times your investment in a year. I'm sure it has the potential. But it won't.

Comment: "My credit card bill is $760 and the due date is next Monday (4 days away)." - whatever is to happen on day 5 is option #3. Which is what?

Comment: @noslenkwah No one told me it was stupid of me I guess. Immaturity!

Comment: @Daman - No need to beat yourself up over this. Scammers are good at what they do. I'd still at least try to get your money back.

Comment: How much do you value the friendship? If the investment flubs, and he needs the money back urgently, what do you do?

Comment: @JuliaHayward Well, I guess I have to borrow it from the bank to give my friend. I'll be a mess then.

Comment: If you have decided to sell the shares that you have invested in, then do it right away, because the money from selling stock will not be available for you to withdraw instantly. It takes time, probably 2 days to be able to withdraw the money back to savings account from trading account.

Comment: @naive it is a very crucial part which I learned today when I tried to sell my stocks.

Comment: Your minimum payment is $760 or your balance?  If it is your balance, why do you need to pay all of it?

Comment: Also you thinking you will only be broke for two months is never true. With this thinking you assume absolutely no issues and starvation. You should not think that you will be only broke for two months try six months.

Comment: How much money do you have left from your salary once you've paid your rent, utilities, and the bare minimum for you to survive? Having a credit card payment of $760 to make when you have $900 in income seems like a huge mistake. I hope $760 is your balance, not your minimum payment.

Comment: @jcaron its full payment. Not minimum

Comment: This might slip into relationship advice, but as a general rule, don't you think you should only borrow from family&friends in extreme cases? It's better to be independent. Indeed, I'd consider selling stock, paying friend, and paying credit card in installments.

Comment: If $760 is the full payment, how much is the minimum? Can you afford that? Pay as much as you can, and learn your lesson.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Don't invest money that you cannot afford to lose at least in the short term.
Don't lend or borrow from friends you cannot afford to lose, same with family members.
Don't borrow money to invest that you don't have covered somewhere else.

In your case you should be focusing on controlling your expenses (i.e. your $760/month credit card bill) and building up your savings.

Oh, and this:

> I have invested in a company that has enough potential to give me 3
> times the return of my invested amount in a year, I guess

Probably not!  you're setting yourself up for a failure.

Comment: Thanks for your input. You are right. There is no point if I am expending too much. And May I know what you meant by this "Probably not! you're setting yourself up for a failure"?

Comment: @Daman what jwh20 means is that the investment in that company will probably not give you the return you are hoping for, and you may even not get back (the full amount of, or any of) your original investment.

Comment: It's that old adage: If it seem too good to be true, it probably is.  Investments that promise extraordinarily high returns, in this case 300% in one year are either extremely risky or a scam.  While there are circumstances where taking on some risk in investing makes sense, your situation certainly doesn't appear to be one of those.

Comment: I need to sell my stocks before I end up in debt thanks to all of you.

Comment: 300% in a year is such an insane return that you might have already lost that money already... Very few things increased by that much, even BTC. The people that got extremely rich off BTC were ones that bought a handful over 10 years ago for pennies and forgot about it (one of my friends did this). Nobody got a 300% return after it started gaining traction. As for my friend that was into BTC, he told me that he actually would've made more money buying the damn coins instead of trying to buy GPUs to mine it way back then. Back then, he made probably $1 out of $300 of GPU investments.

Comment: @Daman "your $760/month credit card bill" — did you actually spend $760 on the credit card in one month? What's the interest rate on the credit card if you don't clear it when due?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Yes, it's spent in 40 days.

Comment: @Daman, this is why people suggest so strongly about having an "emergency fund". This is money you save to spend only in an emergency, preventing you from needing to spend on a credit card or otherwise getting a loan. From the sounds of it, you spent that money on stocks instead, getting you into this situation. Stocks are an investment only if you can afford to leave the money there, and with $10 in the bank, you definitely can't afford to do that, as you see now by spending over $700 in one month. We all make mistakes, just make sure to learn from this one.

Comment: A bit side track, but some recent mainstream IPOs in Indian markets have seen unbelievably  high returns in short periods. (Happiest Minds Technologies Ltd: 800% in 1 year, Route Mobile Ltd: 490% in 1 year, Angel Broking Ltd: 300% in 1 year, Laxmi Organic Industries Limited: 360% in 6 months, Nureca Limited: 310% in 7 months, Easy Trip Planners Limited: 190% in 6 months, ) OP may be referring to one of those. (It's still extremely risky and should not be done unless you have more than you need.)

Comment: @Daman 40 days isn’t one month, but cool.

Comment: @Nelson "Nobody got a 300% return after it started gaining traction." Sorry but this is simply untrue. Dec 2020 BTC was at 15k USD. Even after the recent crash from 60k USD it's at around 45k USD right now. That's 300%+ in less than a year. I'd say that BTC already had an enormous amount of traction before Dec 2020. In crypto these insane gains and losses are easily possible. The ship can also sink just as easily but it's definitely possible.

Comment: Any investment that is potentially returning 300% in one year is also quite capable of losing much or all of its value in that same time period.  That was my point.

Comment: @HattedRooster That's a classic fallacy. You can't look at historical data to extrapolate future worth. Nobody knew when BTC low points were, so there's no way you can capture that 300% and not lose your shirt. The biggest problem with these speculative investment is you have absolutely no indication of its rise and fall, and you will easily invest at the wrong time and lose everything. I do not dispute it happening; I dispute whether anyone can **predict it** and actually **profit from it**. Anyone that claims to have crypto predictions are all lying.

Comment: @Nelson Sure I agree with you there. I also agree that you have no indication of it and thus a huge risk and a huge chance to lose it all. I was merely saying that it did happen and people did profit from it 300%+ even as late as 2021, is it a reasonable investment? No for sure.

Comment: @VivekPabani that's survivorship bias. IPOs are un-predictable, like the rest of the market (by definition) and more risky as there isn't even a stable baseline for valuation. A few anecdotal example shouldn't be the basis for investments

Comment: @HattedRooster hindsight is always 20/20

Comment: A lottery ticket has the *potential* of a 10000000000% return.  Paying on a 15% interest credit card bill has a **guaranteed** 15% return.

Answer (score 40):

Investments with a high risk/reward ratio (such as stock, especially stock in one company rather than a broad portfolio) are more suitable for people who have already built up significant savings buffers in less risky structures.

I am not a financial advisor, but in your shoes I would:

- sell the stocks to pay off the credit card bill
- focus on making and sticking to an achievable budget that allows a certain amount to be put aside regularly in a savings account
- continue saving in the account until you have enough saved to cover 2-3 months normal expenses, and/or the size of any reasonably foreseeable large expense (whichever is larger)
- only look at stock market investments once that savings buffer was secure.

Comment: I really appreciate thanks for your input, Vicky. I am controlling my expenses it's just hard for me Idk.

Comment: Excellent answer, but I'd edit the 3rd bullet point to be saving for 2-3 months of expenses (rent, utilities, food) not 2-3 months of income.  Your income is irrelevant - what you need is a buffer against disaster if the income stops, and that would be the ability to eat and have a roof over your head if there's a disruption to your income.

Comment: @nuggethead thanks, good point.

Comment: Going off what nuggethead said, I'd suggest increasing that amount to 5-6 months, if not 12. It can take many months to find a new job and I'm not sure what India has for Unemployment benefits. It definitely takes a long time to get that much saved, but I can tell you from experience that it's worth it.

Comment: @computercarguy It seems excessive to prepare for 12 months of unemployment; mainly because after more than a few months it is effectively permanent. If you haven't found anything after a few months there are drastic changes ahead in any case.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica, not necessarily. I've been unemployed for +12 months a couple of times and gotten back into the same industry. Granted, because of those massive gaps, I later switched to a related career path and have made considerably more money and been employed much more reliably. And yes, I was trying to make the switch during those long periods of unemployment. Unfortunately, industry, location, # of people in the same industry, and current practices, among other factors, all contribute to problems of unemployment that are beyond the individuals control.

Comment: Also, 12 months is a number I've heard by others and isn't my own recommendation. I will say that the more people have saved, the less likely they will need to pay interest rates on cards and loans.

Answer (score 18):

If I were your friend, I would not loan you $760 knowing that you had $900 tied up in a stock. I would advise you to sell the stock and hope that there's still time to buy back in *if you have the money to do it in 2 months*. Also, if the stock tanks, how are you going to pay your friend back?

You don't *have* $900 to invest in a company regardless of the profit potential.  That's 2 month's salary for you. You need to build up some savings before doing *any* investing.

On top of all of this, I would try to understand how you racked up 1.5 months of CC debt in the first place? How are you going to enure that you don't dig yourself into another hole again?

> I am over buying things. I have no control over credit card I have to get rid of it I guess. I think every month it ll be over and I will save but I don't know I am trapped in this vicious cycle of cc.

That's the root problem. If you don't solve that, the solution for this month is meaningless. Get on a budget. Stop using the CC and pay with cash (or a debit card that is rejected when your account is zero).

Comment: I have got a 10% return from it. I think I am being greedy not selling stock hoping it would go up and " if the stock tanks, how are you going to pay your friend back?" I was thinking of paying him from my salary. Think for a second suppose somehow I managed to survive two months and I got 10% more return or maybe more I won't have  chance to buy back from that low price it will be too late to buy that stock. If I managed this smh I'll be ok after two months isn't it? It's just two months of my life where I have to some struggle and I have money saved in my stocks and in no debt.

Comment: I hear you and know that it's hard to sell winners but I go back to: If you had $900 in cash now, would you buy this stock or pay your CC bill? If it were me, I would pay my bills and try to save up to buy the stock back later. Maybe you lose some in opportunity costs but it's not worth either missing a CC bill or owing money to a friend.

Comment: Note that on top of all of this, I would try to understand how you racked up 1.5 months of CC debt in the first place? How are you going to enure that you don't dig yourself into another hole again?

Comment: I am over buying things. I have no control over credit card I have to get rid of it I guess. I think every month it ll be over and I will save but I don't know I am trapped in this vicious cycle of cc.

Comment: @Daman paying your friend back from your salary is not going to work if you keep spending 1.5x your salary. Even if you were saving half your salary each month, it would still take 3 months to get the money to pay back your friend, not 2 months. (and that's cutting your spending in 3, which is not going to be easy)

Comment: Make a budget. Start simple: 1/ fixed, required expenses (housing, utility bills, debt repayment if any, base food.) 2/ savings (as mentioned in some answers, try to get a few months of basic expenses on the side, to be safe) 3/ free (as in speech, not beer) money that you can spend as you like. The total cannot be above your income. If you want to spend a lot at once, say for a trip or a new computer, save money over several months until you can pay without debt.

Answer (score 17):

1. Don't borrow money from friends or family. The potential damage to the relationship is severe.
2. Sell the stock and pay the credit card.  Is this a minimum payment (meaning you will have a similar bill next month) or do the terms of the card require you to pay in full each month?  It is absolutely vital that you get the usage of this card under control.  If having this card makes it too easy for you to spend more than you can afford, then you need to get rid of it.
3. List all of your monthly expenses and compare that to your monthly $500 income.  If your expenses are near that or more, then you need to find ways to cut back your expenses.
4. Once your finances are lined up and in control, then you can investigate whether your investment opportunity is actually a good place to invest.  Until your finances are under control, it doesn't matter if it is a good investment opportunity.  Right now, you cannot afford to invest.

Answer (score 3):

Stocks will or can crash any day, it's like gambling. Be aware that your stock may only be worth half that in a month (it's possible and it has happened). With that in mind pay what you owe first, then go gamble with the extra money that you don't need.

Answer (score 3):

> Think for a second suppose somehow I managed to survive two months and I got 10% more return or maybe more I won't have chance to buy back from that low price it will be too late to buy that stock.

If the stock is going to give a 300% return in a year, buying back in after a 10% gain is not "too late" at all. In my opinion, this comment combined with the one about having "no control" over your credit card show that you are nowhere near ready to be investing in stocks. First, get your spending under control and pay off debts especially. DO NOT BORROW. Then save up a bit of a cushion. Then take some time for some reading and educate yourself about investing. Then start investing with money you can afford to lose.

Comment: You are right absolutely thanks.